# Bound on sine of sum of angles

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I would like to find tight bounds of the form

$$
f_l(x) g_l(y) \leq \sin( x + y) \leq f_u(x) g_u(y)
$$

Especially for $x \in [0, \pi / N]$ and $y \in [k \pi / N]$ where $k$ and $N$ are integers and $|k| < N/2$. I realize that for a given $N$ the choice of $y$ is finite and therefore tight bounds can be established by taking the maximum or minimum over the set of all possibilities. However, if possible I would appreciate a more analytical approach / formulation.

For example, the identity $\sin( x+ y) = \sin(x) \cos(y) + \cos(x) \sin(y)$ can be used to set some bounds by setting $x$ to the minimum and maximum values.

Comment: What kind of bounds? $f_l\equiv -1, g_l\equiv 1$ and $f_u=g_u\equiv 1$ works.

Comment: @mfl as tight as possible bounds for the given values.